# How to know which site collections a user has access?

Tags: permissions, site-collection, query

I have a web part that needs to identify the site collections the logged-in user has access to. Can Search help with this? Are there better options for me aside from:

1. The web part looping through each site collection to check.
2. Creating a timer job that loops through each site collection to check and stores the results in a list. Then the web part queries from the aforementioned list.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can very well use Search API for getting the list of site collection current user has access to,  provided that you have a good crawl system maintained , probably continuous crawl enabled(only in SP 2013). If you run the KeywordQuery search on current logged in user's context , it will give security trimmed results and it will give only site user have access to.

Below code can be used as a starting point:

```
KeywordQuery query = new KeywordQuery(site);
                    query.QueryText = "ContentClass:STS_Site";
                    query.RowLimit = 500;//max row limit is 500 for KeywordQuery
                    query.ResultsProvider = SearchProvider.Default;
                    query.EnableStemming = true;
                    query.TrimDuplicates = false;
                    query.AuthenticationType = QueryAuthenticationType.PluggableAuthenticatedQuery;
                    query.KeywordInclusion = KeywordInclusion.AllKeywords;
                    SearchExecutor executor = new SearchExecutor();
                    ResultTableCollection resultTableCollection = executor.ExecuteQuery(query);
                    var resultTables = resultTableCollection.Filter("TableType", KnownTableTypes.RelevantResults);
                    var resultTable = resultTables.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to check the permission:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://localhost"))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    // Make sure the current user can enumerate permissions.
                    if (web.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPBasePermissions.EnumeratePermissions))
                    {
                        // Specify the permission to check.
                        SPBasePermissions permissionToCheck = SPBasePermissions.ManageLists;
                        Console.WriteLine("The following users have {0} permission:", permissionToCheck);

                        // Check the permissions of users who are explicitly assigned permissions.                   SPUSer user = web.EnsureUser(loginName);

                            string login = user.LoginName;
                            if (web.DoesUserHavePermissions(login, permissionToCheck))
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(login);
                            }

                    }
                }
            }
```

Also you can refer :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms441848.aspx

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940917/checking-permissions-of-a-user-with-a-site-collection

Comment: Hi Aanchal, thanks for the help! This code can also help but I'm refraining by one-by-one checking each site collection. :)